# How to get 1:1 pixels on android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, resolution, pixel

I created an AVD without screen scaling, but the pixels do not match my screen.

is there any work around for this?

[image]

Screen is configured as 720 wide, but shows as 413 on my screen.

Edit: a little more experiementation, motivated by @Fallenreaper answer:

If I load a 500px wide image in the browser, it's still larger than the screen (which was supposed to be 720px wide).

[image]

Here is the 500px image, with two screen shots, scrolled to the right to show it's larger than the 720px screen.

edit 2:
this may be related to this http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Comment: Based on title of this Q, I was expecting answers that say how to exactly see what screen will look like on a device, especially if the device is higher resolution than will fit on my monitor. Best answer I've found is to use emulator's "screenshot" (camera icon) feature. This will save a file on desktop at the emulated device's full resolution.

Answer (score 4):

When you start the emulator from `Android Virtual Device Manager`, you must check `Scale display to real size`, and then specify `Screen Size (in)` and `Monitor dpi` that calculates to a `Scale` value of `1.0` (or `0.50` if you're on a retina display on OSX).

In my case, I specified a `4.7 in` `Screen Size` and a `160` `Monitor dpi`, which yielded a `0.50` `Scale`. When I take a screenshot of my emulator, it is now pixel-for-pixel what I would expect to see on the device.

You can also specify a command-line option `-scale 1.0` when starting the emulator from the command-line.

If your emulator is already running, you can adjust the scale with the [emulator console](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#console) by sending `window scale 1.0`. This renders too large for me to use on my Retina MBP.

Discover your running emulators with `adb devices`. You should see output like this:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
```

Then, you can connect to the device and send the scale command:

```
$ telnet localhost 5554
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
window scale .50
OK
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

And you can do it in a script with netcat:

```
$ echo 'window scale 0.50' | nc localhost 5554
```

Comment: isn't "no scalling" option the same as this? and If this is the case, how does it explain that i'm not able to show a 500px screen inside a (scaled or not) 720px virtual device screen?

Answer (score 0):

each device has a different pixel density, so if you want to adjust it to be a 1-to-1 ratio, you will need to determine the devices pixel density, and compare with that of your host machine... then scale accordingly.

The different pixel densitieswill cause 1 to be bigger then the other, so if you are designing a screen, your textboxes would look right, being like 30x 150, but on the device, 30x150 would be far smaller.

Source:  I do iOS and Android Web App Dev for WebViews and i have ran along this because i do it every day.

Comment: good point, but dpi is fixed for each screen. if the emulator is running on my desktop, unless the software is scaling it in software, it is impossible to have a different dpi. otherwise it would not only look different size, but also blurry. the emulator is pixel perfect, meaning it really is 418px in whatever dpi my monitor is using. you can confirm that by the image test i put there.

Comment: Different emulators emulate different phones, screen, OS, and all. I honestly dont use emulators because of some issues with hardware.  just get 1 android phone and use that. :)  There are hidden overhead coxsts of the emulator which make certain things slower, or just non-functional.

Comment: the emulator now in 2016 is very, very fast.
but the control tools are very buggy right now.

1:1 pixels would be nice to have.